# Predictions for classes on which the DNN was not trained yet - is that possible?

Tags: deep-learning, keras

my data is of multi-class, multi-label type, and I plan to have 100 output classes in total.

My input `X` to the model is audio data, my `y` is a one-hot encoded numpy array with 100 columns showing a `1` to indicate the respective class (e.g. `y = [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...`]

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(...) # more layers ... CNN ...
model.add(...) # more layers ... LSTM ...
model.add(Dense(512, input_dim=n_inputs, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
```

At the moment, I only have audio files belonging to only 12 (of the planned 100) classes. Which means that 88 columns of `y` are **not** assigned any `1` currently.

Then after training with the current 12-classes data (NSize ~ 16000), I run `model.predict(...)` and get probabilities for almost all of the 100 columns, some of them quite high percentages.

Is this possible that a model outputs quite high prediction probabilities for classes which it never received as input? Any suggestions to fix that? (I can almost 100% exclude an error on the one-hot encoding of `y`)

Kind regards,
ziggyler

Answer (score 0):

Deep Learning models try to learn different unique properties of a class from training samples. With enough training samples the model learns which feature corresponds to which class. So without any training samples, there is no chance that a model will learn to classify to that class. But you can use pretrained models that requires little to no training samples as they are trained on huge dataset.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So it seems that I have a general underlying problem for my model if I'm getting high probabilities (0.7 and above) for classes which are not even present in the training data .... :(